# Связать две таблицы в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, join

Есть 2 таблицы вида

Таблица #1 - `client`

```
id  status (varchar)  login (varchar)   password (char)

1   enabled           qwerty            wrbujhwprijp;ji
2   enabled           wjkb              w;rbjowrobi
3   disabled          vorochenko        wpribjhbrkw;jbn
```

Таблица #2 - `balance`

```
id  id_client  date(date)        amount(decimal(8,2))

1   1          2015-04-04           100.00
2   1          2015-04-04           -40.00
3   2          2015-04-04           -50.00 
4   3          2015-04-04            80.00
5   2          2015-04-04            120.00
6   1          2015-04-04           -45.00
```

Требуется:
По каждому клиенту необходимо получить сумму его баланса, дата операции, статус клиента не важны.
У клиента могут отсутствовать какие-либо записи об операциях вообще, но в отчете он должен присутствовать.
Пример отчета с перечнем полей

```
idclient (int)   amount (decimal)
    1              15.00
    2              70.00
    3              80.00
    4               Null
```

Сделал вот такой запрос :

```
SELECT `idclient (int)`, SUM(`amount`) FROM `balance` GROUP BY `idclient (int)`
```

но он не подходит, ибо не учитывается 4 юзер

Comment: у вас в таблице `Таблица #1 - client` 3 записи, откуда вы взяли 4-го?

Comment: я забыл вписать)
4 есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). Конкретно в вашем случае, вам нужно в выборку добавить все записи из таблицы `client`, даже у которых нет соответствующих в таблице `balance`. Для этого в ваш запрос достаточно добавить `RIGHT JOIN`.

```sql
SELECT
    c.`id` AS `id_client`,
    SUM(b.`amount`) AS `sum`
FROM `balance` AS b
RIGHT JOIN `client` AS c 
    ON b.id_client = c.id
GROUP BY c.`id`;
```

Comment: в результирующей таблице в первой строке возвращает 
 idclient - null
 amount -null

потом идет все как надо.
нужно, что бы возвращало idclient - 4,
а amount - null

Comment: Выводите и группируйте по c.id

Comment: @gudfar поправил запрос

Comment: @korytoff
спасибо большое)
очень помог